# Nuxt 3 doesn't recognize formkit and doesn't style it

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I was trying to use formkit with nuxt3.
I imported in the nuxt.config.ts like this:

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
   modules: ['@formkit/nuxt'],
})
```

But when i try to use it in my components it is not recognize and drops an error:
[image]

and is not styled in the broswer

[image]

Comment: are you using volar?

Comment: have you added the css in the nuxt.config.ts file?

Answer (score 2):

Use this as your nuxt config.ts

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: ['../src/module', '@formkit/nuxt'],
  formkit: {
    configFile: '../formkit.config.ts',
  },
  myModule: {},
});
```

and formkit.config.ts

```
import { DefaultConfigOptions } from '@formkit/vue';

const config: DefaultConfigOptions = {
  theme: 'genesis',
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 0):

using a vue plugin worked for me

```js
// file: plugins/formkit.ts
import { defaultConfig, plugin } from '@formkit/vue'
import config from '~~/formkit.config'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(plugin, defaultConfig(config))
})
```